# Is there data on how England's European Parliament constituencies voted in the 2017 UK General Election?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, european-parliament, data-sources

For some research/data analysis I would like to find electoral data from the 2017 UK general election aggregated by European Parliament constituency.  For Scotland, Wales, and NI, these data are readily available since the EP constituencies are coterminous with those polities.  However, I have not been able to find similar data for England's European Parliament regions.  I could always aggregate constituency and ward data manually, but it would make my life much easier if there was ready data aggregating the results by  English EP constituency.

Comment: I don't know of a source for the precompiled data, but is a lookup table from westminster constituency to EU election region any use? http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/313c62d49cb24376a2fad7ac7939fda5_0 That ought to allow the problem to be scripted fairly quickly...

Comment: I trust you're already aware that this is not a meaningful measure of how the mood of the British people between 2017 and 2019?

Comment: You can find a list of Westminster constituencies within each European Parliament constituency (contiguous with regions) here: https://beta.parliament.uk/find-your-constituency

Comment: @Joe C makes an important point.  Be aware that througout the EU, the EU elections always have a low turnout (often driven by anti-european sentiment) and the 2017 UK General Election had a very high (possibly more representative??) turn out.  The two are not directly comparable

Answer (score 4):

I have collated this data by using the look-up table mapping from UK Parliament constituency to European Parliament constituency provided by the [Office for National Statistics](http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/313c62d49cb24376a2fad7ac7939fda5_0), as well as the official per-constituency results of the 2017 General Election, available from the [House of Commons Library](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-7979/).

The results are below. Note that the calculated overall winner is not strictly accurate in the context of European elections, as they do not use the FPTP voting system.

**Image:** (adapted from [original](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:UK_European_Parliament_constituency.svg))

[image]

**Data:**

| european_constituency | electorate | valid_votes | invalid_votes | con | lab | ld | ukip | green | snp | pc | dup | sf | sdlp | uup | alliance | other | other_winner | winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| East Midlands | 3415899 | 2357458 | 5251 | 1195982 | 954635 | 101612 | 56358 | 34355 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 14516 | 0 | con |
| Eastern | 4433341 | 3094309 | 7354 | 1690813 | 1012357 | 244054 | 77793 | 58704 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10588 | 0 | con |
| London | 5464504 | 3828498 | 10650 | 1268800 | 2086595 | 336725 | 49369 | 67561 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 19448 | 0 | lab |
| North East | 1938346 | 1280066 | 2275 | 440613 | 709738 | 58409 | 49348 | 16080 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5878 | 0 | lab |
| North West | 5301084 | 3595506 | 7751 | 1301562 | 1972632 | 193053 | 68946 | 39608 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 19705 | 0 | lab |
| Northern Ireland | 1242698 | 812183 | 2886 | 3895 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7452 | 0 | 0 | 292316 | 238915 | 95419 | 83280 | 64553 | 26353 | 16148 | dup |
| Scotland | 3988441 | 2649695 | 3902 | 757949 | 717007 | 179062 | 5302 | 5886 | 977568 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6921 | 0 | snp |
| South East | 6513697 | 4635887 | 11890 | 2495350 | 1326380 | 487203 | 104509 | 143873 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 78572 | 34299 | con |
| South West | 4181099 | 3002659 | 6411 | 1542296 | 875213 | 448730 | 33160 | 68010 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 35250 | 0 | con |
| Wales | 2298161 | 1575814 | 2788 | 528839 | 771354 | 71039 | 31376 | 5128 | 0 | 164466 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3612 | 0 | lab |
| West Midlands | 4132560 | 2766222 | 6929 | 1356486 | 1175095 | 122287 | 50106 | 46347 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 15901 | 0 | con |
| Yorkshire and The Humber | 3926703 | 2605887 | 6101 | 1054099 | 1276912 | 129687 | 67801 | 32661 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 44727 | 0 | lab |